# What url should i use for create unique page?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, database, url

I am creating a REST API "news" project. I have a question, how can I create a correct get url request in get mapping in order to display a specific article on the site. For example, suppose I have two articles with titles:

1. **JAVA IS BETTER**
2. **JAVA IS BETTER**

These are two different articles with the same title, how can I create the correct url for a page to display a certain news. I have some ideas, but i think that they not so good.

1. @GetMapping("/api/news/{article.id name}") -> not correct how to improve this?
2. I had an idea to create new entity in DB that will count number of articles and when user will add new articles, this entity will take his number.
   @GetMapping("/api/news/{articles.counter.number}") -> so "complex"
3. Use id in url, but I read that is bad idea.
   @GetMapping("api/news/{article.id}")
4. Most news cites have url like this:
   .../news/desperate-search-survivors-enters-second-day-after-florida-condo-collapse-n1272333

What is this n1272333? is it id or special field in db of entity aricles or just number article in DB?

Comment: ID in URL is not as bad as people make it out to be, it's simple and many search engine doesn't really care as long as you don't have a crazy complex URL. You can read the following article for more information https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/url-structure
personally, I would suggest creating a `URL slug` like `JAVA-IS-BETTER` and `JAVA-IS-BETTER-02` where the last part is the id or count.

Comment: how about /api/news/{article.id}/{versionNumber}/java-is-better ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to include the article title in the URL, then use something like what @shikida suggested in his comment on your question:

`/api/news/{article.name}/{article.id}`.

You could also use a slug like what @DebashisDip suggested:

`/api/news/{article.name}-{article.id}`.

Having the ID in the URL is not a bad ideas as long as you are following best practices for authorization in your API and securing your database.